# OpenGL building hierarchy transform system

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm trying to build transform system, imitating Unity's. See my code:

```cpp
void BaseObject::RecalculateTransform()
{
    // For top object
    if (parent.expired())
    {
        worldTransform = localTransform = glm::mat4(1);
        return;
    }

    // bunch of shit
    localTransform = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), localPosition) * glm::scale(glm::mat4(1), localScale) * glm::mat4(localRotation);

    worldTransform = parent.lock()->GetWorldTransform() * localTransform;
}
```

This is how I'm calculating the local transform and world transform. I've tried pretty a lot of combinations of the order of transformation matrices, but none of them worked correctly. I tried to reference Unity3d, but couldn't get something useful.

`localPosition` and `localScale` is `glm::vec3` type, and `localRotation` is `glm::quat` type.

As it maybe helps, I picked a screenshot from above code:

```cpp
auto top = app->GetHierarchy()->GetTopObject();

auto childDepth1 = top->Instantiate().lock();
childDepth1->SetLocalPosition(glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

// spiral one
auto mesh1 = childDepth1->AddComponent<RandomMesh>().lock();
mesh1->SetVerticeData("l 30");

auto childDepth2 = childDepth1->Instantiate().lock();
childDepth2->SetLocalPosition(glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

// spherical one
auto mesh2 = childDepth2->AddComponent<RandomMesh>().lock();
mesh2->SetVerticeData("s 100 t");
```

Screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the spiral one has the sphere as it's child. spiral one's `localPosition` is `(0, 1, 0)`, an so is the `worldPosition`. But it's rendered on `-y` location. (I have confirmed that `+y` location is above the middle line in other way.)

Moreover, the sphere's localPosition is also `(0, 1, 0)`, which makes it's `worldPosition` `(0, 2, 0)`. Keeping direction that `+y` location is beneath the middle line, it must be rendered beneath the spiral one, but it's rendered *over* the sphere. With debugging with printing, it says that the sphere's `worldPosition` is `(0, 0, 0)`, not `(0, 2, 0)`.

After some experiments, I figured out that the transform matrix is applied plus and minus, depending the odd-evenness of the child depth.

What I want is just Unity-like transform system.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What if you do `worldTransform = localTransform * parent.lock()->GetWorldTransform();` isntead?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I've tried this and nothing changed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to my stupid mistake. When I was initializing `localRotation` quaternion value, I was doing

```cpp
localRotation = glm::quat(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

I don't know exactly why, but with debugger it negated the position value every time when the rotation matrix from this has multiplied.

The correct initialization is

```cpp
localRotation = glm::identity<glm::quat>();
```

which will not apply rotation at all, *as the name suggests*.

Here is my solution:

```cpp
void BaseObject::RecalculateTransform()
{
    isTransformChanged = false;

    // For top object
    if (parent.expired())
    {
        worldTransform = localTransform = glm::mat4(1);
        return;
    }

    const auto& scaled = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1), localScale);
    const auto& rotated = glm::mat4(localRotation) * scaled;
    const auto& translated = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), localPosition) * rotated;

    localTransform = translated;

    worldTransform = parent.lock()->GetWorldTransform() * localTransform;
}
```

All is fine. It's already midnight in Korea. I can finally go bed.
For someone who faces the same problem with me, please do not be stupid :(